# Add a column to a VSTO ListObject that has an existing data source?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, excel, vsto

Does anyone know how to add a column to an existing list object in Excel, one that has already got a data source bound to it from a SQL source?
I just want to add another column with a formula in every cell for that column of data, to match whatever amount of data is showing at the time.

I have the below 2 examples of what I have tried so far, 1. Gives a syntax error only at runtime of `Syntax error: Missing operand before '=' operator`. 2. Gives an obscure COM exception.

1.

```
    Dim prodDateCol = New DataColumn("Prod Date", GetType(System.Int32),
    "=LEFT([Production Code],4)")
    ComplaintsListObject.ListColumns.Add(prodDateCol)
```

2.

```
    Dim objListCol = ProdListObject.ListColumns.Add()
    Dim listColRange = objListCol.DataBodyRange
    listColRange.Cells(1, 1) = "=LEFT([Production Code],4)"
```

I know alternatively I could do this using the Excel cells after first checking each time the list object changes in size, but before looking into how to do that in more detail.. I was hoping there was a way to do this using the List Object itself.

Anyone got any examples or suggestions?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I have adjusted this slightly for testing and also looked more at the use of `.Expression` and it only allows certain functions, so I have changed `LEFT` to `SUBSTRING`.
This example still returns a COM exception of `Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))`

```
    Dim prodDateCol As DataColumn = New DataColumn
    prodDateCol.ColumnName = "Prod Date"
    prodDateCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
    prodDateCol.Expression = "SUBSTRING([Production Code],1,4)"

    ComplaintsListObject.ListColumns.Add(prodDateCol)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Dim prodDateCol As New DataColumn`... ?

Comment: I've made an update just to be clearer. I don't think you have to specify the type in your example.